# DIBI subquery - order, limit order

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table, e.g.:

```
ID Text 
1 AAAA 
2 BBBB 
3 CCCC 
4 DDDD 
5 EEEE 
6 FFFF
```

if I use: $result= dibi::query('SELECT * FROM [tabulka] ORDER BY [id] DESC LIMIT 3 '); I get result:

```
FFFF 
EEEE 
DDDD
```

but I need this:

```
DDDD 
EEEE 
FFFF
```

Any help would be appreciated... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `LIMIT 3` subquery in another subquery which generates the ascending ordering you want:

```
SELECT Text
FROM
(
    SELECT Text
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t
ORDER BY Text;
```

[image]

### Demo